# Python: Sort list of lists by size (reversed) and store the original indices

Tags: python, list

basically a combination of this:

```
[x[0] for x in sorted(MYLIST, key=len, reverse=True)]
[x[0] for x in sorted(MYLIST, key=lambda i: i[1])]
```

Comment: please provide an example code

Answer (score 0):

If we say that `lst_of_lst` is the original list,

```
sorted_lst = [(len(lst), lst) for lst in lst_of_lst]
sorted_lst = sorted(sorted_lst, reverse = True)
sorted_lst = [lst for (length,lst) in sorted_lst]
```

`sorted_lst` is the new sorted list.

However, this code may not work depending on how you want to treat cases where two lists have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

Because `sorted` and `enumerate` are iterators, it's not really possible to get the effect you want using them together in a single loop. So, instead we gather the info you want seperately.

```py
nested_lists = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
]

# Capture original indices
indexed_lists = [(index, sublist) for index, sublist in enumerate(nested_lists)]

# sort them by length of sublist
sorted_lists = sorted(indexed_lists, reverse=True, key=lambda item: len(item[1]))

# Iterate over the sorted object, printing the old and new indexes
for new_index, (old_index, sublist) in enumerate(sorted_lists):
    print('old index:', old_index, 'new_index:', new_index)
    print(sublist, end='\n\n')
```

The output would be in reverse length order (largest to smallest) printing the old and new indices like this:

```
old index: 0 new_index: 0
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

old index: 3 new_index: 1
[1, 2, 3, 4]

old index: 2 new_index: 2
[1, 2, 3]

old index: 1 new_index: 3
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted` in conjunction with `enumerate` and provide the method with the `key` and the `reverse` parameters. Below, `lst` is sorted by length, then reversed.

For example, if you have a list like so:

```
lst = [[29,53,27], [34,34,76,23,65], [32,39]]
```

You can use `sorted` and `enumerate` in a one liner:

```
sorted_lst = sorted(enumerate(lst), key=lambda v: len(v[1]), reverse=True)
```

Which returns a list of tuples with the original index position as the first value and the list as the second value:

```
[(1, [34, 34, 76, 23, 65]), (0, [29, 53, 27]), (2, [32, 39])]
```